# Return Font Awesome Icon from Rails controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, controller, font-awesome

I’m creating a rails app where User can add Room to favorite. Everything is working well.
I just want to customize my link to adding to favorite.

Actually I have a jQuery function :

```
$('#favorite_link').text("<%= favorite_text %>")
```

And in my controller, i have :

```
def favorite_text
    if @favorite_exists
      "UnFavorite"
    else
      "Favorite"
    end
  end
  helper_method :favorite_text
```

U just want to change my "Unfavorite" and my "Favorite" by a font Awesome Icon.

```
<i class="far fa-bookmark"></i>
```

and the second one :

```
<i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
```

I tried many stuff but failed !
Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Many thanks

Comment: The first and second icon are identical?

Comment: Hi, Not exactly "far" VS "fas", one is empty of color, second one is full of color.

Comment: Hey Basil could you resolved it? I actually did this tutorial and im finding the answer for this

Comment: Hey Ken, i didn't resolved yet, i will have a look to your bellow tutorial , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attribute an `id` to the icon and then change its class with `jQuery`. If you have multiple "favorite" icons on the same page, make sure the `id` is unique to each `Room`. Example:

```
<i id="favorite-icon" class="<%= favorite_class %>"><i>
```

And the helper method:

```
def favorite_class
  if @favorite_exists
    "fas fa-bookmark"
  else
    "far fa-bookmark"
  end
end
helper_method :favorite_class
```

To change it using `jQuery`:

```
$("#favorite-icon").attr("class", "<%= favorite_class %>");
```

You could make it look nicer by getting the `i` element from the `#favorite_link` element, but I don't know your HTML structure. That way you won't need an aditional `id` for the icon.

Comment: Hi Flàvio, my html structure is really simple : <li><%= link_to favorite_text, favorites_update_path(room: @room), id:'favorite_link', remote: true %></li>. Should i add <i id="favorite-icon" class="<%= favorite_class %>"><i> in ? Many thanks –

Answer (score 0):

For those who needs to add an icon instead of just text(Im using material icons):

This took me about 8 hours to figure.

**The views (shows):**

```
<%= link_to favorites_update_path(property: @property), remote: true do %>
      <i id="favorite-icon" class="<%= favorite_class %>">favorite</i>
<% end %>
```

**update.html.erb:**

```
$("#favorite-icon").attr("class", "<%= favorite_class %>");
```

**application Controller:**

```
def favorite_class
  if @favorite_exist 
     "material-icons-two-tone purple-icons"
  else
     "material-icons-two-tone"     
  end
end    
helper_method :favorite_class
```